# Extending CollectionType in Swift 2

Tags: generics, dictionary, swift2

So i'm trying to extend the CollectionType protocol in Swift 2

```
protocol CollectionAccess: CollectionType {
    func getElement<T: Hashable>(key: T) -> Self.Generator.Element?
}

extension Dictionary : CollectionAccess {
    func getElement(key: Key) -> Dictionary.Element? {
        if let value = self[key] {
            return (key, value)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

When it compiles it throws an error that :

> error: type 'Dictionary' does not conform to protocol
>   'CollectionAccess' extension Dictionary : CollectionAccess

the function getElement(...) compiles fine and works fine as a n extension of Dictionary by itself BUT not as

```
extension Dictionary : CollectionAccess
```

=====progress======================

i managed to get rid of the error by changing my signature in the Dictionary extension:

```
extension Dictionary : CollectionAccess {
    func getElement<K: Hashable where K == Dictionary.Key>(key: K) -> Dictionary.Generator.Element? {
        self[key]
```

Now the issue is:

> error: cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary' with
>   an index of type 'K'
>           self[key]

What I'm going for is setting up the signature to say the K is the same Hashable as the Dictionary.Key type is.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will be possible - CollectionType doesn't have a generic that corresponds to Dictionary's 'Key' generic. I.e. not all CollectionType's consist of key value pairs, so therefore it doesn't make sense to make CollectionType have a Key /Value type method.  For example another CollectionType is Array - what would get element return for an array?

Comment: In other words, 'Key' and 'Value' are placeholders in Dictionary, so you can't access these in the method signature for a CollectionType protocol extension.  Please forgive me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Key' and 'Value' are placeholders in Dictionary, so you can't access these in the method signature for a CollectionType protocol extension - so to get this to work you have to do a cast.

It seems slightly wrong to me, but I think you can just about get it to work with something like this:

```
extension Dictionary : CollectionAccess {
    func getElement<T : Hashable>(key: T) -> Dictionary.Generator.Element?     {
        if key.self is Key.Type {
            let tKey = key as! Key
            if let value = self[tKey] {
                return (tKey, value)
            }
         }
        return nil
    }
}
```

The thing is, CollectionType doesn't have a placeholder that corresponds to Dictionary's 'Key' placeholder. Not all CollectionType's consist of key value pairs, so therefore it doesn't make sense to make CollectionType have a Key / Value type method. For example another CollectionType is Array - what would getElement return for an array?

Comment: thanks @james_alvarez, this seems to work for now. I agree with you it does feel a bit off to me still. I am still trying to wrap my brain around the protocol extensions where Self is referenced in the declaration and all that.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to change the declaration of your protocol you can also solve this by making an associated type requirement:

```
protocol CollectionAccess: CollectionType {
    typealias T = Hashable
    func getElement(key: T) -> Self.Generator.Element?
}
```

Now your dictionary implementation works as expected without modification.

(But now you cannot create arrays of type `[CollectionAccess]` (only as parameter in a generic function where is has to be "homogeneous"))